# Play Framework - How to keep the configurations of my module inside it?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, typesafe-config

I am using Play Framework 2.2.x/Java.

I want to create a module to sperate some of the logics from my main application and also I want to use the **application.conf** inside the module ***for its configurations*** instead of using the main application's config file!

But using the following snippet in the module, only reads values from the main application config file:

```
Play.application().configuration().getString("myVar");
```

Is there any other way to get the values from the **application.conf** file inside my module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Play uses the [typesafe-config](https://github.com/typesafehub/config) library for reading configuration. This is actually a Java library, even though Typesafe is a Scala company.

The documentation for typesafe-config says "The idea is that libraries and frameworks should ship with a reference.conf in their jar."

So your module's config should be stored in a file called `reference.conf` - the format is exactly the same, it's just the name that is different.

The problem occurs because there is a conflict between the two config files because they are named the same, so it probably goes by classpath order or something. Don't use two `application.conf` files - this problem has bitten me in the past!

Comment: Does that apply to Play v1.x as well?

Comment: No, Play 1.x does not use typesafe-config.

Answer (score 2):

Save your config into ie. `/conf/my-module.conf` of the main app and then include it at the end of `application.conf` like:

```
include "my-module.conf"
```

Comment: Yes, this should also work, but it should not be necessary to add the `include` - see my answer.